# Перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++

Можно ли перегрузить вот такой парный оператор: `[]=`.
Т.е. обращение по индексу к внутреннему полю и запись в него значения.

Comment: можно, но что именно ты хочешь сделать? что потом оператор должен сделать ?

Comment: a[i]= 5, то есть к i элементу присвоить 5. я верно  вас понял ?

Comment: моя цель установить бит в unsigned short по индексу этого бита
unsigned short - поле объекта
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В С++ нет такого оператора как `[]=`. Но есть операторы `[]` и `=`, каждый из которых можно перегрузить.

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы имеете в виду следующее

```
#include <iostream>

class Point
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point( int x = 0, int y = 0 ) : x( x ), y( y ) 
    {

    }

    const int & operator []( size_t i ) const
    {
        return i == 0 ? x : y;
    }

    int & operator []( size_t i )
    {
        return i == 0 ? x : y;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Point p;

    p[0] = 10;
    p[1] = 20;

    std::cout << "p = { " << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << " }" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль

```
p = { 10, 20 }
```

EDIT: Если вы собираетесь использовать этот оператор для манипулирования битами в целочисленном числе, то посмотрите, как реализован класс `std::bitset`. Так как вы не можете возвращать ссылку на бит, то вводится дополнительный промежуточный класс reference, который и управляет битами.

Вот как определяется этот оператор в `std::bitset`, который позволяет установить нужный бит

```
reference operator[](size_t pos);
```

А в классе reference определен оператор неявного преобразования типа

```
operator bool() const noexcept;
```

Для ваших целей этот оператор будет выглядеть как

```
operator value_type() const noexcept;
```

где `value_type` определяется как

```
typedef unsigned int value_type;
```

Comment: моя цель установить бит в unsigned short по индексу этого бита

Comment: unsigned short поле объекта

Comment: @КонстантинФомин В этом случае вам следует посмотреть реализацию стандартного класса std::bitset. Там это делается посредством введения дополнительного класса reference, так как вы не можете вернуть ссылку на бит. Поэтому возвращается ссылка на этот класс, который и управляет битами в числе.

Comment: можно в объекте сделать метод устанавливающий бит (что и сделано на данный момент). Я просто озадачился - а можно ли этого добиться просто перегрузив операцию? 

Отсюда вопрос. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Про bitset я знаю. но несколько не подходит - не та задача :-)

Comment: @КонстантинФомин Я привел std::bitset, в качестве примера приема, как можно определить этот оператор, чтобы установить конкретный бит. Вы можете позаимствовать этот прием.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже сказали, оператора `[]=` не существует.
Но можно перегрузить оператор `[]` и возвратить из него объект, в котором вы можете перегрузить оператор `=`, в котором уже и произвести нужные операции.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  int operator =(int n) {
    cout << "Setting val to " <<  n << endl;
    return n;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  A operator [](int i) {
    return A();
  }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  int n;
  b[4] = 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
Setting val to 1
```

Comment: Знаете, пожалуй, проще и разумнее возвращать ссылки :)

Comment: @Harry в моём случае созданный объект нигде не хранится, поэтому ссылку я возвращать не могу. Я привёл только пример того как это можно реализовать, а детали автор может (и должен) подогнать под себя.

Comment: Мое мнение - показывать лучше на более-менее имеющем практическую ценность примере. Переопределение присваивания вообще чревато с той точки зрения, что это легко может обернуться изменением семантики...

Comment: @Harry понятно, ну значит наши мнения отличаются :)
Моё мнение таково, что пример должен быть наикратчайшим рабочим.

Comment: моя цель установить бит в unsigned short по индексу этого бита
unsigned short - поле объекта
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Vladimir Pavluk а не будет в Вашем варианте утечек памяти?
Идея неплоха, но из за простой установки бита... - не стоит городить огород.

Comment: @КонстантинФомин нет, в моём варианте утечек не будет. А в остальном вам виднее наверное, я просто предложил вариант, как можно реализовать то, что вы спросили. Если бы вы рассказали сразу чего вы хотите добиться, пример мог бы быть другим.

Comment: @VladimirPavluk Все равно, спасибо за ответ! Идею я понял.